# PHP BEST way to do PregMatch store and compare the true or false value in an if statement

Tags: php, regex, variables, preg-match

Hi I am using pregmatch for the first time and I can get it to echo out the true or false and it looks great. However when I try to store the value so I can compare in an if statement if the value was true or not (for error message) it fails? I put a question mark because when I echo it out it says 'True', but when I compare it nothing happens, nothing gets added to my concatenated string. I have tried many different ways including adding a third value in the pregmatch to store it but no luck.

My Current code is:

```
$check = (preg_match($patternFullName,$FullName))?'True':'False';

    if($check == true)
    {
        $errorMessage += "Thank you $FullName for your submission. You submitted: $FullName";
    }
    else
    {
        $errorMessage += "hey";
    } 

 echo $check;
```

So I store the true or false value in check and it doesnt compare and add to my string. But echoing the check out it gives me the true or false. Not really sure what the issue is or how to solve this type of issue. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: just say if($check == "True");

Comment: I tried this and no luck

Comment: Thanks i tried with single quotes too

Comment: Did you see the edited solution by the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compares the variable $check with a string "True"/"False" to a bool value true:

```
if($check == true)
```

This is what you are after:

```
$check = (bool) preg_match($patternFullName,$FullName);

if ($check)
{
    $errorMessage .= "Thank you $FullName for your submission. You submitted: $FullName";
}
else
{
    $errorMessage .= "hey";
} 

echo ($check ? 'True':'False');
```

The (bool) just converts the integer returned by preg_match to a boolean true/false type. true if one or more matches was found, false if not.

Edit: changed += to .= for string concatenation.

Comment: Is there really a need to cast the return from preg_match? It's already a Boolean value.

Comment: @Charles it is an integer, like I explained. I like my boolean values as boolean if Im gonna store them in a variable. If I use it directly in an if I don't.

Comment: I see what you mean, I can dig it! Note to self, don't confuse intergers 0 and 1 with booleans, unless when php does auto type casting in statement evaluations. I can dig it!

Comment: @lighty It works for me. I didn't notice you had a string concatenation error before since it wasn't a part of your original question.

Comment: @OIS, neither did I men, gotta get JS outta my head.

Comment: Yes I put a dot and it worked. How come it is not += ? Thank you also

Comment: @lighty + is javascript string concatenation notation, or in the case of PHP, simply to add numbers, or numbers to strings after converting both to numbers. String concatenation in PHP is done with the "." operator.

Comment: @lighty because of so called "weak typing" 3 + "3" = 6 and 3 . "3" = "33"